# Network interface auto renamed from emX to ethX

Tags: networking, 20.04

I had hostname updated using hostnamectl and then rebooted the server. The server was unreachable after as the network interface changed from em1 to eth1. My /etc/network/interfaces file had em1 due to which it failed to raise the interface.

Is there any reason why suddenly Ubuntu 20.04 decided to change from emX to ethX?
Was that due to change in hostname?

Comment: The /etc/network/interfaces method is deprecated in Ubuntu 20.04. In a server installation, network configuration is set in /etc/netplan.

Comment: @chili555, if I want to set a permanent network configuration, should I be using /etc/netplan going forward? It seems Ubuntu 20.04 still took the config from /etc/network/interfaces. Should I be removing config or that file completely?

Comment: You should restore the /etc/network/interfaces file to its default as originally installed. Then check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359916/network-configurations/1359923#1359923